# transitions in a sequence

Tags: r, dplyr, stringr

I have a dataset and I would like to the probability of transition.

So I have three alphabets like this (13 states) which are possible:
CCE    CRE    DEE    FOE    GOE    ICE    ISE    MEE    PCE    PRE    PSE    RLE    WAE

For example,

```
 # A<- c('A-A-A-B', 'A-A-A-A', 'A-B-C-D', 'A-A')
 A<- c('CCE-CRE-DEE-DEE', 'FOE-FOE-GOE-GOE-GOE-ISE', 'ISE-PCE', 'ISE')
 library('stringr')
 B<- str_count(A, "-")
 df<- data.frame(A, B)
```

I would like to get the transition among the letters, for example in the total transitions (how many are to other states assuming A,B,C,D are different states?),

I am expecting output as follows:

B here is total transitions occurring in sequence
C here is the total transitions to other states

```
    df$C   
    1        
    0        
    3        
    0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `rle` from base R,

```
sapply(strsplit(A, '-'), function(i)length(rle(i)$lengths) - 1)
#[1] 1 0 3 0
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use gsub from base R:

```
 str_count(gsub('(\\w+)(-?\\1)+','\\1', A),'-')
```

EDIT:
to get the unique counts, just add 1 to the results you have